# Enforce newline but not pagebreak?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking

In different part of my text I utilize `\newline` (because I need to force a new line break), but how do I ensure that the new line don't also seperat or make a page break right after the newline command?

This should only be applied to some (not all) newlines.

*Typing in LuaLaTex with document class `memoir`.*

EDIT

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{memoir}

\begin{document}

~\vspace{19.5cm} \\
First line of tex \\%*
Second line of tex

\end{document}
```

Here is the output after running the above code (image):

[image]

Comment: ``\\*``  should normally work.

Comment: A Minimum Working Example (MWE) would help here as it would be useful to know what kind of situation you want to have a page break and what kind you don't. In general a minipage, hbox, or vbox might be a way to achieve your goal depending on the specific nature of what you are after.

Comment: `\\*` doesn't work for me in `xelatex` with `article` document class.