# Avoiding blank lines in document

Tags: line-breaking

I have a command `\wvDeductj` that includes some text at the beginning of a line.

With

```
\wvDeductj{This} Text
```

the `Text` gets printed next to `This`.

What is the procedure to write text on the next line without introducing a blank line ?

```
\wvDeductj{This} 

Text
```

Would one change `\wvDeductj` or do something else to `Text` ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \wvDeductj {O{orange}om}
  {
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {
          \bgroup\par\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
          \color{#1}#3\egroup\hspace{5mm}
        }
      {
        \bgroup\par\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
        \color[#1]{#2}#3\egroup\hspace{5mm}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\wvDeductj{This} Something Something

\wvDeductj{That}
Something Something

\end{document}
```

Comment: you shouldn't start a paragraph in a group, that can have curious side-effects. If you really don't want to create a semantic, meaningfull command, then better use `\noindent\textcolor{#1}{#3}\hspace{5mm}`. Avoiding `\noindent` by using worse code is not really sensible.  And regarding the new line see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/502911/2388

Comment: why a new account with the same name? (why so many accounts a day)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not know how you determined that one user has many accounts. But if it is based on domain name when the account is created: I often use the Internet at the nearby university, which permits me to have a guest account. When web sites notice that I arrive from a university domain, I routinely get ads directed toward students. And it thinks that I live about 200 miles away, which is where the server is located.

Comment: @rallg we know that it is the same user because of the content of the questions.  It is rather obvious. Also the user doesn't deny that they create a new account every few hours.

Comment: @rallg this user thinks it is amusing to ask a question then delete the account leaving an orphaned question on which he won't be notified even if someone answers it. currently in excess of an account per day

Comment: @rallg as predicted this account has been deleted a new one will no doubt appear shortly in a new question

Comment: @rallg See [Printing on same line or on next line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698436/printing-on-same-line-or-on-next-line)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle et.al.: Ah, I see. Is there any possibility that this is an AI bot? But even if it is, that would not explain why accounts are repeatdly added and deleted. You would think that AI would be proud of itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say to add `\par\noindent`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \wvDeductj {O{orange}om}
  {
    \par\noindent
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {
          \textcolor{#1}{#3}
        }
      {
        \textcolor[#1]{#2}{#3}
      }
    \par\nopagebreak\noindent\ignorespaces
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\wvDeductj{This} Something Something

\wvDeductj{That}
Something Something

\end{document}
```

Beware that a blank line between `\wvDeduct{...}` and the following text is not allowed, in that it would produce an indentation.

[image]